# auto-wiring a custom event when custom control is double-clicked within design view

Tags: winforms, user-controls, event-handling

Basically, I added a custom event to my TreeView derivative.  It is meant to replace the AfterSelected Event, which I disable, because I require a different Event handling mechanism for when people click on tree items.

The event handling itself works well.  But I want my new event to be the one wired when a custom control is doubled-clicked in the design view.

The custom class is called CustomTreeView, and this is how it declares its new event.

```
public event EventHandler CustomSelect;
```

So basically, when double clicked in the design view, I want this to appear in the  MyForm.Designer.cs

```
this.MyCustomTreeView.CustomSelect += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventHandler(this.MyCustomTreeView_CustomSelect);
```

And obviously, the MyCustomTreeView_CustomSelect() function should be added to MyForm.cs

so how do I set this up in my custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the [`DefaultEventAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute.aspx)

```
[DefaultEvent("CustomSelect")]
public class MyCustomTreeView : TreeView
{
    //...
}
```